# Set physical path for telerik file uploader

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a TELERIK file upload control and i want to set the physical path for the uploaded image. for example c:\desktop\images here i want to store uploaded image and then get the same file from stored path and use it as an mail attachment.please help me do the same..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OnFileUploaded server event of radAsyncUpload to obtain the uploaded file and save it as a stream: https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/asyncupload/server-side-programming/onfileuploaded